# php readfile('folder/subfolder'.$_GET['userInput']) security issue?

Tags: php, security, file-io

I have a `page.php?id=example` and in `page.php` :

```
readfile('folder/subfolder/'.$_GET['id']);
```

The `id` variable is a string and can possibly take infinite distinct values so it would be difficult be enumerate them in the php ?

At the most I could verify all the characters are letters.

If `id` did `readfile($_GET['id'])`, I understand one could read any php file and have my code and database passwords.

But using `readfile('folder/subfolder/'.$_GET['id'])`:

- I'm aware of `../` but I tried it and it doesnt seem to work ? It
  tells me: `readfile(folder/subfolder/../../index.php): failed to open
  stream: No such file or directory`
- If I checked each time the presence of `.` and `/`, would it be
  enough or are there other similar tricks ?
- Should I use an int `id` instead of a string ?
- Should I do otherwise ?

Comment: Use `int` ID or allow nur chars `[A-Za-z0-9-_]` to be supplied.

Comment: Which type of files do you wish to allow for reading?

Comment: M1K1O Thanks, I prefer the string version so mu url looks better

Comment: Hanky 웃 Panky : only text files

Comment: Use `realpath()` to resolve the path, and then check if the path starts with the required prefix (ie. `folder/subfolder/`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **never** pass user input to file operations. Even if you escape all '.', you'll never know if there is some new security issue out there.

So you can

- whitelist the user input, e.g., by using `in_array` to check whether the user input is defined in your list.
- use numeric ids as you mentioned above (so you can escape the user input by `(int)`).
- if you have to use string input, just allow defined characters, e.g., validate the input by using `preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/', $_GET['id']);`.

Comment: If I checked the variable is only made of these characters, would I still need to check the directory or would it be sufficient ?

Comment: The folder is not defined by the id, isn't it? So if you check for the characters, the id won't contain a `.` or a `/`. See this example:

`$id = $_GET['id'];`
`$file = '/your/path/'.$id.'.txt';`
`if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/', $id) && file_exists($file))`
`readfile($file);`

Comment: Sure but I wanted to be sure that there is no other way than "../" to get out of the path. Thanks then I'll probably simply do that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some answers to your questions here : [Security issues with PHP's Readfile method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799333/security-issues-with-phps-readfile-method)

Now, about the "Should I do otherwise ?", I'd say that you **could** do otherwise.

Not talking about checking the type of the files you want to give access to, which should be easy enough, I'd add an 'authorized_files' file (or use a database by the way, depends on the amount of file you've) to any considered sub_folder and use it as a list of the authorized files that can be accessed through readfile.

```
if (in_array($_GET['id'], file('authorized_files'))) {
    readfile(...);
}
```

Edit : Ah right, if it's about reading .txt files only, checking the type should be a way easier and the best way to do probably